# How to build a new Ruby array from a Hash keys

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I want to build a new array starting from a hash with the following format:

```
HashConst = {[120,240] => 60, [240,480]=> 30} #Constant
```

I need to build a new array and assign as value to a new constant with the following format:

```
[ [[120,240] ,1], [[240,480], 1] ]
```

I tried :

```
NewArrayConst = HashConst.keys.each{ |res| [res, 1]}
```

but I get instead

```
[ [120,240], [240,480] ]
```

Only solution I found is the following:

```
  tempVar = []
  HashConst.keys.each_with_index{ |res,idx| tempVar [idx] = [res, 1]}
  NewArrayConst = tempVar
```

Anyone knows a better solution to this and can explain why I cannot get the output I expect from `NewArrayConst = HashConst.keys.each{ |res| [res, 1]}`. I'm using `2.2.2-p95`

Edit:

As many pointed out Hash var name is wrong and misleading, I have updated that to avoid confusion

Comment: You are using the very class `Hash`. Redefining it is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `map` instead of `each`.

[`Array#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) method does not return the result of the code executed in the block, but instead just returns the array on which `each` was called, which in your case is the value of `hash.keys`.

[`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) collects the values returned by block into an array.

```
hash = {[120,240] => 60, [240,480]=> 30}
p array = hash.keys.map{ |res| [res, 1]}
#=> [[[120, 240], 1], [[240, 480], 1]]
```

---

**NOTE**: Do not name your variable `Hash` as it is already a well-known class in Ruby.  Use lower case `hash` if need be. Also, avoid camel case for variable names such as `NewArrayConst`, as Ruby recommends use of `snake_case` for naming variables - you can refer [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#naming) for more details.

Comment: That works and thank you for the explanation. I had the wrong idea that each collected and returned the  array of the executed expression

Comment: @mgtemp In what sense? I mean, if you need to create a new array, you need to create a new array.

Comment: @mgtemp compared to what? And a prooflink would be great here.

Comment: `Hash` is a "well-known" class? Never heard of it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland May be it should have been named `Hush`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but map creates a new object and stores the values in that new object. If you work with a big enough array or run the map enough times more objects means more work for the GC. The GC has improved in Ruby 2.0 and beyond, but isn't perfect. I'm not saying OP has a better option or it will slow his program severely, but in general the less objects you create the better.

Comment: https://pragprog.com/book/adrpo/ruby-performance-optimization is a great resource for learning how to speed up ruby code.

Comment: @mgtemp Yes, it creates a new object--that's its purpose.

Comment: So if he's looping that block 10000 times he'll have a problem. Right?

Comment: @mgtemp Depends on a variety of factors. If the data is as shown but times 10k, no.

Comment: @mgtemp See https://gist.github.com/davelnewton/1fdaafc1ba3944a6bae8, it's < 2M memory for a hash of 10k elements and the corresponding array, for 100K it's 9M, for 1M it's 45M, give or take, and runs in 4s.

Comment: Very good observations,in my particular case the worst case is 2k elements and only executed once, so It has no so much big impact on performance according to DavE measurements

Answer (score 3):

```
h = {[120,240] => 60, [240,480]=> 30}
val = 1

h.keys.product([val])
  #=> [[[120, 240], 1], [[240, 480], 1]]
```

Comment: This has the advantage of knowing how large the resulting structure will be "in advance", so if there *are* memory re-allocations involved during a `map` as mgtemp suggests, they *may* be avoidable.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried `Hash.to_a`? Sometimes things are easier than you think.

Comment: Why don't you leave that up to @maza, .to_a gives us `[[[120, 240], 60], [[240, 480], 30]]' which is in the format @maza described.

Comment: But not what they're actually *asking* for. I don't see the confusion.

Comment: As usual, @Dave is picky-picky.